# Replace multiple duplicate lines with spaces in Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++, regex

I have a text file like this:

```
eeeeeeee6fd6e6e7000000800010884f image_0001.png                                                   
eeeeeeee6fd6e6e7000000800010884f image_0002.png                                                   
e6eee7afef77c6c7000000808860003b image_0003.png                                                   
e6eeefa7cfe777170100000008886033 image_0004.png                                                   
e6eeefa7cfe777170100000008886033 image_0005.png                                                   
eeeecfe7afcfe7770100000030088c27 image_0006.png                                                   
efebefe7a7cfc7e70101080000300c03 image_0007.png                                                   
ef6befdf674f97c7000000900200301f image_0008.png                                                   
ef6befdf674f97c7000000900200301f image_0009.png                                                   
6d6d6faff767479700004008810000e1 image_0010.png                                                   
ed6d6dada5f767570000400098830401 image_0011.png                                                   
ed6d6dada5f767570000400098830401 image_0012.png                                                   
efed6d4da595f7a70202004000181303 image_0013.png                                                   
ebececcc2f2797f10000008051043c5b image_0014.png                                                   
e9edecce4e6e26ba120101808058042a image_0015.png                                                   
e9edecce4e6e26ba120101808058042a image_0016.png                                                   
ececeeefcf6f67a61000000080585887 image_0017.png                                                   
cc6ceeefcf4f67e710000020000149d8 image_0018.png                                                   
cc6cefefefcf6fe71000000040000001 image_0019.png                                                   
cc6cefefefcf6fe71000000040000001 image_0020.png                                                   
8ceceeefefcfcfe700000000c0000009 image_0021.png
```

and I'd like to use Notepad++ to get rid of all but one each of any duplicate strings (hash values on the left) and leave that part of the line blank, retaining the file names on the right-hand side, like this:

```
eeeeeeee6fd6e6e7000000800010884f image_0001.png                                                   
                                 image_0002.png                                                   
e6eee7afef77c6c7000000808860003b image_0003.png                                                   
e6eeefa7cfe777170100000008886033 image_0004.png                                                   
                                 image_0005.png                                                   
eeeecfe7afcfe7770100000030088c27 image_0006.png                                                   
efebefe7a7cfc7e70101080000300c03 image_0007.png                                                   
ef6befdf674f97c7000000900200301f image_0008.png                                                   
                                 image_0009.png                                                   
6d6d6faff767479700004008810000e1 image_0010.png                                                   
ed6d6dada5f767570000400098830401 image_0011.png                                                   
                                 image_0012.png 
...etc.
```

Of course there are many different strings that need replacing so it's not as easy as one would think (especially for thousands of such lines).
Is there a regex or any other way to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to do it directly with Notepad++ or regex, but you could easily do it with Python or virtually any other language.

Comment: @ GordonAitchJay That's all well and good but I'm hopeless at coding- I can do some *very* rudimentary python coding, but for this problem, maybe I'd need advice about modules to use etc.. maybe I'll post in a more pythony area.. Thanks

Comment: No worries. See my answer. It's a simple 13 line program, excluding the comments (everything after the #s). I've edited your question so it now has the Python tag.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what program made your file hashes textfile, and why do you want to remove duplicates hashes?

Comment: I edited your question to simply add the `Python` tag, but the edit was rejected. "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability." Apparently adding a tag doesn't make it easier to find or more accessible. Oh well, my answer should be sufficient.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay Thanks - I used https://github.com/Jetsetter/dhash to produce the hash values, I wrote a simple python script to print out the results of multiple values of images, in order to find out which frames in a video were repeats (i.e. the camera was faulty at 4k resolution and was dropping frames every so often) and I wanted to remove them to create a less jerky video, I was looking to this as a first step in a process to determine which frames to get rid of. 
I realise I can use imagemagick etc to acheive this but was trying to work something out from first principles so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this with Python. Here's one way:

```python
# Note: Your output file must be different to your input file!
# Use absolute filepaths unless the files are in the current working directory.
input_filepath = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\file hashes.txt"
output_filepath = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\file hashes (processed).txt"

hashes = set() # This set keeps track of known file hashes
with open(input_filepath) as fin:
    with open(output_filepath, "w") as fout:
        # After opening both the input and output files,
        # loop over every line in the input file.
        for line in fin:
            # Get the hash, which is between the start of the line and the first space.
            file_hash = line[:line.find(" ")] 
            # Check if it is in the set of known hashes.
            # If it is, write the current line without the hash to the output file.
            # If it isn't, write the current line with the hash to the output file,
            # and add the hash to our set of known hashes
            if file_hash in hashes:
                hash_len = len(file_hash)
                fout.write(" " * hash_len + line[hash_len:])
            else:
                fout.write(line)
                hashes.add(file_hash)
```

`file hashes (processed).txt` looks like:

```
eeeeeeee6fd6e6e7000000800010884f image_0001.png                                                   
                                 image_0002.png                                                   
e6eee7afef77c6c7000000808860003b image_0003.png                                                   
e6eeefa7cfe777170100000008886033 image_0004.png                                                   
                                 image_0005.png                                                   
eeeecfe7afcfe7770100000030088c27 image_0006.png                                                   
efebefe7a7cfc7e70101080000300c03 image_0007.png                                                   
ef6befdf674f97c7000000900200301f image_0008.png                                                   
                                 image_0009.png                                                   
6d6d6faff767479700004008810000e1 image_0010.png                                                   
ed6d6dada5f767570000400098830401 image_0011.png                                                   
                                 image_0012.png                                                   
efed6d4da595f7a70202004000181303 image_0013.png                                                   
ebececcc2f2797f10000008051043c5b image_0014.png                                                   
e9edecce4e6e26ba120101808058042a image_0015.png                                                   
                                 image_0016.png                                                   
ececeeefcf6f67a61000000080585887 image_0017.png                                                   
cc6ceeefcf4f67e710000020000149d8 image_0018.png                                                   
cc6cefefefcf6fe71000000040000001 image_0019.png                                                   
                                 image_0020.png                                                   
8ceceeefefcfcfe700000000c0000009 image_0021.png
```

I'm not sure how Python is setup in your system, but you should be able to run it by copying the above code into a file named something like `remove_duplicate_hashes.py`, then running it by double clicking it or entering `python remove_duplicate_hashes.py` into your command prompt.

Comment: That worked well and helped me grasp the code concepts a lot better, thanks.